# Prolog sum predicate, when is the temp variable instantiated?

Tags: recursion, prolog, sum

I'm trying to understand this sum predicate

```
 sum([], 0).
 sum([H|T], Sum) :-
    sum(T, Temp), 
    Sum is Temp + H.
```

It works however I don't understand why. From my understanding with a query such as sum([1,2,3], Sum) it will match on the second clause instantiating H as 1 and T as [2,3] and Sum is still Sum. Then it will attempt to satisfy the first sub goal calling sum again but in the second goal where Sum is Temp + H when is Temp given a value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Temp` is given a value first in the base case, `sum([],0)`. That causes `Temp=0` in the recursive call above. The call above that adds `H` to give `0+H`, etc.

To convince yourself of this, trace the execution of your query:

```
?- trace.
true.

[trace]  ?- sum([1,2,3], Sum).
   Call: (6) sum([1, 2, 3], _G376) ? creep
   Call: (7) sum([2, 3], _G455) ? creep
   Call: (8) sum([3], _G455) ? creep
   Call: (9) sum([], _G455) ? creep
   Exit: (9) sum([], 0) ? creep
^  Call: (9) _G460 is 0+3 ? creep
^  Exit: (9) 3 is 0+3 ? creep
   Exit: (8) sum([3], 3) ? creep
^  Call: (8) _G463 is 3+2 ? creep
^  Exit: (8) 5 is 3+2 ? creep
   Exit: (7) sum([2, 3], 5) ? creep
^  Call: (7) _G376 is 5+1 ? creep
^  Exit: (7) 6 is 5+1 ? creep
   Exit: (6) sum([1, 2, 3], 6) ? creep
Sum = 6.
```

(The `creep` is me hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd>; this is SWI-Prolog.)

Comment: Ah okay I forgot about using trace cheers, I was think that would cause Temp to be set to 0 each time but I'm guessing because temp is not 0 it would cause the first predicate to fail?

Comment: The first predicate only succeeds when `T` is `[]`.

Comment: @Barmar: you mean the first clause, there's only one predicate.